# Will I get any benefit from making my controller method async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have this controller method below. First example is sync, second example is async. I didn't add an await, but put it into a task.Run()

Will there be any benefit in making it async here and would this be the proper way to do it?

sync version

```cs
[HttpGet("authsignature")]
public IActionResult GetSignSignature([FromQuery] string folder) {
  
  DateTime foo = DateTime.Now;
  long timeStamp = ((DateTimeOffset)foo).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
  var p = new Dictionary <string, object>();

  p.Add("folder", folder); 
  p.Add("timestamp", timeStamp);


  var signature = _cloudinary.Api.SignParameters(p);

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature)) {
    return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400));
  }

  return Ok(new {
    cloudUploadUrl = _config.GetSection("CloudinarySettings:CloudUploadUrl").Value,
      cloudName = _cloudinaryConfig.Value.CloudName,
      cloudApiKey = _cloudinaryConfig.Value.ApiKey,
      cloudSignature = signature,
      cloudTimeStamp = timeStamp
  });

}
```

async version

```cs
[HttpGet("authsignature")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSignSignature([FromQuery] string folder) {
  
  DateTime foo = DateTime.Now;
  long timeStamp = ((DateTimeOffset)foo).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
  var p = new Dictionary <string, object>();

  p.Add("folder", folder); 
  p.Add("timestamp", timeStamp);


  var signature = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_cloudinary.Api.SignParameters(p)));

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature)) {
    return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400));
  }

  return Ok(new {
    cloudUploadUrl = _config.GetSection("CloudinarySettings:CloudUploadUrl").Value,
      cloudName = _cloudinaryConfig.Value.CloudName,
      cloudApiKey = _cloudinaryConfig.Value.ApiKey,
      cloudSignature = signature,
      cloudTimeStamp = timeStamp
  });

}
```

Comment: Please take more care when formatting code - bits of C# server code are *not* executable JavaScript snippets.

Comment: What's the best way to copy/paste c# code? The '{}' button?? If I use the {} button and paste, it doesn't format it and I have to spend more time editing it than if I use the JS editor.

Comment: I just left-align it in VS (so that the indentation is all "even"), paste it in, and then put triple backticks around it with the `csharp` language at the top. (See my edit for an example.) I would definitely encourage you to think about readers rather than your own time - if you're asking other people to spend their time helping you, it's really incumbent on you to spend *your* time presenting the information as well as possible.

Comment: @user1186050: See: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/328193)  *"If I use the {} button and paste"* - I'd recommend switching the order of events.  If you can paste the code already sensibly indented then you can highlight it and press `{}` to further "indent" it for the markdown editing.  *"it doesn't format it and I have to spend more time editing"* - Sometimes it takes a little effort to format and present one's question.  This is not a bad thing.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the 3 backticks with the csharp tag or the order of events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ["Synchronous vs Asynchronous request handling" section of my article on async ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#synchronous-vs-asynchronous-request-handling).

In summary, asynchronous code allows your server to handle more requests by using fewer threads.

However, `await Task.Run` like in your example is not true asynchronous code: it's just placing synchronous work on the thread pool. The same thread pool used by ASP.NET to handle requests. So `Task.Run` is just doing a thread switch for no benefit. From later in that same article:

> You can kick off some background work by awaiting Task.Run, but there’s no point in doing so. In fact, that will actually hurt your scalability by interfering with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics.

Assuming "SignParameters" is an actual API you're calling, then proper asynchrony would look something like this:

```
var signature = await _cloudinary.Api.SignParametersAsync(p);
```

Comment: Hi Stephen SignParameters doesn't have any async call. I originally had a async call just to fetch my user at the top of the function, but thought that was unnecessary because I didn't need it. Am I stuck just keeping this as sync?

Comment: @user1186050: Yes. If your API doesn't have an asynchronous API, then it is best to keep it synchronous (on ASP.NET).